# $q.all for dynamic number or promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, q

Trying to figure out how to use $q for a dynamic list of promises.

Right now requests_arr.then() fires before the 2nd promise is resolved.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong, or how I should fix things up so q.all.then() works as it should?

```
request_components_array = [0,1];

var request_que = _.map(request_components_array, function(components,i){

    return $timeout(function(){

        return self.getStuff().query({})

    }, 1000*i+1);

});

var requests_arr = $q.all(request_que);

requests_arr.then(function(data){

  cb(data);

})
```

Comment: What is `self.getStuff().query({})`?

Comment: This should work. How do you know when the promises resolve, can you post your exact code including the side effects (like `console.log` instead of `cb`)?

Comment: probably need to return the `$promise` if that is a `$resource` being used

Comment: @JustinYoung yes, I think you need to do that

Comment: @charlietfl you were right:

 
    return self.getStuff().query({}).$promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resource` has a `$promise` property that you need to return

```
 return self.getStuff().query({}).$promise
```